# Print value in the same mysql column into multiple columns with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to output a table with all of the things I need from a product to display in a webpage and then reorganize in another table elsewhere for reference.

I have ***my_posts***, ***my_postmeta*** TABLES.

In ***my_posts*** table i have the ***post_type*** which as to be '***product***' and the ***post_title*** which is the name of the product. I also have the ***ID*** of the product.

Then i have the other table ***my_postmeta*** which have **two** values in the same column ***my_postmeta.meta_key*** which are '**_sku**' and **'_regular_price'**.

I made a query that can print something like this:

[image: Image01]

The Query:

```
SELECT  my_posts.post_title, 
    my_posts.post_type, 
    my_posts.ID, 
GROUP_CONCAT(my_postmeta.meta_value) 
FROM my_posts 
INNER JOIN 
    my_postmeta 
ON 
    my_posts.ID=my_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE 
    my_posts.post_type 
LIKE    'product' 
AND 
    my_postmeta.meta_key IN ('_sku', '_regular_price') 
GROUP BY 
    my_posts.post_title
```

But i want to separate the values '_sku', '_regular_price' in diferent columns. 
Like this :

[image: Image02]

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use two join on my_postmeta and not group_concat

```
  SELECT  t1.post_title, 
      t1.post_type, 
      t1.ID, 
  m1.meta_value  as regular_price,
  m2.meta_value  as sku,
  FROM my_posts  t1 
  INNER JOIN  my_postmeta m1 ON t1.ID=m1.post_id and m1.meta_key= '_regular_price'
  INNER JOIN my_postmeta m2 ON t1.ID=m2.post_id and m2.meta_key= '_sku'
  WHERE  t1.post_type LIKE    'product'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it worked after a few modifications :).
Code: 
SELECT my_posts.post_title, my_posts.post_type, my_posts.ID, m1.meta_value AS price, m2.meta_value AS sku FROM my_posts INNER JOIN my_postmeta AS m1 ON my_posts.ID=m1.post_id AND m1.meta_key='_regular_price' INNER JOIN my_postmeta AS m2 ON my_posts.ID=m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key='_sku' WHERE my_posts.post_type LIKE 'product' ORDER BY `sku` ASC");